# Schema - How To Reference Internal Review Stars On Every Page?

Tags: structured-data

I am fairly new to structured data markup and I have decided implement a review/star rating system on my website for my clients to leave reviews for my services. I will be using software called "Commentics" to do so, as I already use it for my blog's commenting system. Aside from the obvious onsite value I want to get the star/review (aggregate) ratings to show up in my search results. I just learned that Commentics supports rich snippets by default once that feature is enabled in admin and from what other users are saying, it seems to work beautifully for getting stars to show up in their search results for pages the comments are displayed on. My dilemma is, I don't want to have to include the comments on every corresponding page. For example: I only want to place the comments on the page - Reviews.php, but include Schema/JSON-LD/microdata/etc markup in my footer-include.php and somehow reference my internal reviews on Reviews.php in hopes of getting star/review ratings on all of the corresponding pages. The Commentics developers seem to recommend using microformat for the commenting system itself, by the way...

It seems that a lot of people are using the following markup for star/review ratings:

```
@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Organization",
"url": "http://www.siteexample.com"
"aggregateRating": {
"@type": "AggregateRating",
"ratingValue": "4.9",
"bestRating": "5",
"worstRating": "1"
"ratingCount": "89"
```

Firstly, that seems very shady, because people can simply put whatever numbers they want for the ratingValue and ratingCount and a lot of the sites that I see doing this don't even have onsite internal reviews. Secondly, this would obviously have to be manually calculated and updated constantly as reviews are submitted...

So, is there any kind of markup I can include in my footer-include.php that would reference the comments (along with the ratingValue and ratingCount) on my Reviews.php page?

Any help or suggestions you guys can offer would be greatly appreciated. I'm completely lost...

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have figured out a solution. Possibly even a couple of solutions... What if I put something like this in my footer to reference my Reviews.php?

```
<span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">Overall rating of
<span itemprop="ratingValue">5.0</span> out of 5 based on a total of
<span itemprop="reviewCount">30</span> customer reviews from the following source:

5.0 out 5 based on <a itemprop="url" href="https://www.example.com/Reviews.php">30 customer reviews on Mysite.com</a>
</span>
```

**- OR -**

If I wanted to reference my Reviews.php page AND multiple offsite reviews, how about this?

```
<span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">Overall rating of
<span itemprop="ratingValue">5.0</span> out of 5 based on a total of
<span itemprop="reviewCount">60</span> customer reviews from the following sources:

5.0 out 5 based on <a itemprop="url" href="https://www.example.com/Reviews.php">30 customer reviews on Mysite.com</a>
4.8 out of 5 based on <a itemprop="url" href="https://plus.google.com/review-page">20 customer reviews at Google+</a>
5.0 out of 5 based on <a itemprop="url" href="https://www.facebook.com/review-page">10 customer reviews at Facebook</a>
</span>
```

Would either of these work?

Comment: The problem I see with either of those is, again, I would have to be constantly updating all of those ratings manually... Is there a way to do this so all of the ratings would automatically update?

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is anyone that is going to be able to help me out with this, but just in case, here is an update. I have at least learned that Google recently changed their guidelines and no longer allows webmasters to markup external reviews, as I was doing in one of my examples above. So, at this point I simply need help coming up with the proper microdata markup to reference my internal reviews on the appropriate pages. Is there anyone, who can help me out with this?